# Unexpected end of Input at SafeSubscriber - HttpClient Angular 5 after POST Request

Tags: typescript, angular5

I found this problem after doing a POST request in HttpClient of Angular 5. Request was successful, but `HttpErrorResponse` came back

Here is the below error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input↵    at SafeSubscriber._error (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:353:13)↵    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:18031:16)↵    at SafeSubscriber.error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17990:26)↵    at Subscriber._error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17921:26)↵    at Subscriber.error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17895:18)↵    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17921:26)↵    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17895:18)↵    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17921:26)↵    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17895:18)↵    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17921:26)
```

Here is my method for Saving the data

```js
createUser(customer: Customer) {
        return this.httpClient.post<ResponseMessage>(this.cnsts.getUserCreateURL(), customer, {responseType: 'json'})
        .map(res=> this.data = {
            errorMessage: res.errorMessage,
            status: res.status,
            otp: res.otp
        });
    }
```

Here is my code to subscribe to that post request:

```js
onSubmit(registerForm: NgForm) {
    if (this.isEmailExist) {
      this.alerCtrl = this.createAlertControl();
      this.alerCtrl.present();
      return;
    }
    if (registerForm.value.password != registerForm.value.confirmPassword) {
      let tstCtrl = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: "Passwords are not matching!!!",
        duration: 3000
      });
      tstCtrl.present();
      return;
    }
    this.loginSvc.createUser(new Customer(registerForm.value.name, registerForm.value.email, this.mobile, registerForm.value.password))
      .subscribe((data: ResponseMessage) => {
        console.log(data);
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Please help me resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the response is actually json? If not change `responseType: 'json'` to `responseType: 'text'`. Otherwise share the details from the network tab from your browser where you can see all the `http` information in the response and the request.

Comment: Hi @Igor, I tried as you suggested. No luck. Interesting thing is the json(which is sent back from the API call) is in error body. But not in the success part. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did a blunder by replying 404 even if it was a success. My bad. Lesson learnt, never try to over smart WebApi